# Youtube protocol for streaming on iPhone

Tags: ios, streaming, youtube, rtmp

I read that Youtube sends iPhone devices MP4 format files rather than normal flv, as iPhone has no suppprt for Flash and RTMP. Do they change the protocol too ? What protocol does does Youtube use for streaming on iPhone ? Can I use RED 5 streaming solution for streaming "to" iPhone ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use IIS - it's free and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for certain, but they *should* be using Apple HTTP Live Streaming.

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Answer (score 0):

They probably use HTTP to "stream" the MP4 files, just like the Youtube website does with .flv and now .f4v (which is basically .mp4 anyway).

As long as the MP4 files are created so that all the important metadata is located at the beginning of the file, before the video and audio data starts, any player can play the file just like a local MP4 file, even though it's still being downloaded. No special protocol is needed.